# How parse datetime format from datebase?

Tags: c++, sqlite, date, datetime

The database (SQLite) has a field of type REAL with the values of the form (42153.659595).
How to translate this value in the form "dd.MM.yy HH:mm:ss" if 42153.659595 = 29.05.2015 15:49:49 ?

Comment: I found out that the whole of the (42153) is the number of days from 1900:
42153/365 = 115.4876712328767.
2015 - 1900 = 115.
But how exactly is considering count leap years?
And that means the fractional part?

Comment: The fractional part is the number of seconds divided by the seconds in a day (86400) 0.659595 = 49/3600.0 + 49/86400.0 + 15/24.0. For the integer part you are better off looking at date conversion functions. Even gmtime, if 2038 bug is not a problem for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct value is achieved using the API/builtin SQL functions (**42153.659595** - value from database):

```
SELECT datetime(julianday(42153.659595, 'localtime') + 2415018.29167) AS DT;
```

Output:

```
          DT       |
2015-05-29 15:49:49|
```

Constant **2415018.29167** was selected manually and query:

```
SELECT datetime (2415018.29167);
```

returns the current Greenwich Mean Time.

I work with a third-party application and documentation on the database is missing. Perhaps this strange decision, but it works. Thank you all for answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can be explicit about what calendar system you require: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

```
SELECT julianday('now') - julianday('1776-07-04');
```

In principle just *don't* "parse" (you mean: interpret raw representation). Use Sqlite API/builtin SQL functions to do it for you

In the interest of information:

- The date and time functions use **[a subset of IS0-8601 date and time formats](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)**.
- The datetime() function returns "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS". The julianday() function returns the Julian day - the number of days since noon in Greenwich on November 24, 4714 B.C. (Proleptic Gregorian calendar)
- The date() function returns the date in this format: YYYY-MM-DD. The time() function returns the time as HH:MM:SS.

Comment: There is no `gregorian` modifier.

Comment: @CL. Mmm. That's interesting. I grabbed the example from [an older version of the docs](http://www.sqlite.org/cvstrac/wiki?p=DateAndTimeFunctions). I updated the link to newest version before posting the answer though. It might be changed, or simply dropped from the docs? Anyways, the answer still stands; the docs are patient :)

Comment: That example was never correct (at least for SQLite 3); this query returns NULL.

Comment: @CL. what are you trying to say? That the old documentation was incorrect (even though you didn't test it)? I think it's not very important.

Comment: It was possible to choose a number 2415018.29167 that work correctly in the following combinations:
"SELECT datetime (julianday (42153.659595, 'localtime') + 2415018.29167);": we obtain the required value: "29-05-2015 15:49:49". If you perform a "SELECT datetime (2415018.29167, 'localtime') AS dt;": we get "1899-12-30 00:00:00". Thus, the database stores dates in the Julian format since 1900.